# Running a .bat only within sub-directory from a .bat in root directory?

Tags: batch-file, file-organization

I have a series of commands that moves files from folders A-E to one folder X, e.g.:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
    'dir /s /b ^| find /i "\Folder A\"'
    ) do move "%%a" "G:\Folder X"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (
    'dir /s /b ^| find /i "\Folder B\"'
    ) do move "%%a" "G:\Folder X"
```

etc

and once they're in X, running a .bat within X to sort those files based on their names into folders by name:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%b in ('dir /b *.pdf') do (
    md %%b > nul 2>&1
    move *%%b*.pdf %%b
    )
```

but it seems to want to run the .bat within X in the root folder instead of only `\X\`.  Is there any way to tell it to run `X\*.bat` only within X?  Aside from changing `*.pdf` to `X\*.pdf`?  I'm trying to write so that each .bat is as portable as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, the only problem is that the current directory doesn't change, and you'd like to change it to `G:\Folder X` when you run the batch file in that folder.

You could do this from the "parent" batch file:

```
pushd "G:\Folder X"
call "G:\Folder X\process.bat"
popd
```

Or from within the "child" batch file you could force it to always set its current directory to the directory containing the batch file:

```
pushd "%~dp0"
:: do your stuff
popd
```

Comment: Great! Please mark the answer as "accepted" if it answered your question.  That will help others searching for an answer to the same question, and it also thanks the answerer with some "reputation". Same goes for the other questions you've asked recently--it looks from your comments like some of them have been useful, but none have been marked as "accepted".